# VBA Problems: Windows.Visible = False

Tags: excel, vba

I created a form for employee registration, and query results. The projetc is simple, but I decided to create a menu and hide the Workbook, but now all other UserForms are having constant problems.
For example, all my RowSource to load information in ListBox stopped working.

One of the most frequent errors is: Run-time error "380". "Cannot set RowSource property"

```
Me.ListBox1.RowSource = "Names"
Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount = 3
Me.ListBox1.ColumnHeads = True
```

And the worst thing is that everything works again if I simply disable the code to hide the Workbook.

Does anyone know what could be going on?

I've done everything I can think of, including using the code to hide just the specific Workbook, but nothing works.

Comment: Your question needs [minimal relevant] code and description of a *specific* problem.  "stopped working" doesn't tell us much about what's going on.

Comment: Sorry, the list is long.
To simplify, one of the most frequent errors is:

Run-time error "380".
"Cannot set RowSource property"


But worth saying: This only happens when the Workbook is hidden.

Comment: We don't need a list of *all* the problems, just one or two reproducible ones.  Ideally the first one(s) which pop up.

Comment: You should provide either the code raising the problem or a abstraction of it which reproduces the error. Otherwise it is nearly impossible to guess what exactly you are doing and what goes wrong. For example look at the documentation which states:  Although code in your control may still run while invisible, you will not be able to interact with the control through the user interface. If you want to create an invisible control that still responds to user input (for example, mouse clicks), you should create a transparent control.